# What is meaning of "beaten hands down"?

Tags: meaning

The full sentence is this : But most doctors are beaten hands down by countless alternative practitioners who might not know a lymphocyte from a lump of cheese.

Thank you.

Comment: Kindly split this question into two. That way your answers to each question can be independently managed.

Comment: Your second question should be asked separately, and a good deal more clearly than it is at present.

Answer (score 2):

To be beaten *[hands down](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/win-hands-down.html)* is to be thoroughly and easily defeated in a contest. The expression derives from horse racing.

Comment: Note that there's a significant difference between "beaten down" (as in the question title) and "beaten hands down" (as in the quoted text).

Comment: @HotLicks Adjusted title.